# did Uther Doul manipulate the Brucolac into mutiny? If so, what was the point?

Tags: china-mieville, the-scar

So In China Mieville's 'The Scar', Uther Doul's behavior in many ways contributes to the Brucolac's decision to commit mutiny, making it seem like Doul manipulated the Brucolac into it. Firstly, the Brucolac finds out about the Scar to begin with because when he guesses that it is the goal of their quest, Doul chooses to not deny it. The Brucolac then makes the assumption that Doul wanted him to know because he needed someone to confide in, because deep down he (Doul) knows that this mission equates to suicide. Basically the Brucolac then feels like it's his job to stop the quest, and that despite denying it up-front, Doul secretly or subconsciously is on his side.  Moreover, despite the fact that the Brucolac and Doul have face-offs in public, the Brucolac seems to have some strange camaraderie ideas about Doul; he is disappointed that Doul is not his man, he feels like even though Doul is the enemy he is 'closer' to him as opposed to his political allies. Etc.  In fact, when the Brucolac has already committed mutiny and is about to murder the Lovers, he seems to think that Doul may be convinced to not interfere with him overthrowing the Lovers.

So then, it seems like psychologically, Doul manipulated the Brucolac into munity the same way he manipulated Bellis. My question is, what was the point of that? With Bellis, the point is clear -she put the right people in the right place at the right time to get a popular rebellion going. But the Brucolac's rebellion lead to his capture, the murder of his cadre, and his public torture until someone else starts a different popular rebellion. I don't get the point of that at all. If Doul didn't want the Brucolac to turn the city around by force, why did he egg him into it? It seems like all along Doul wanted the brucolac to rebel, and actually planned to defeat him. But why was it necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Doul did some possibility mining and figured out that in order for Tanner Sack's revolution to be successful the people need to be pissed off/tired/worn out by war already, therefore tipping the scales just enough against the lovers' plan for Tanner to finally add the final push. Basically, Tanner's revolution and Brucolac's mutiny both added just enough social pressure to set things in motion...